# Copy code from one solution to another c # (Visual Studio)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

sorry for my English, I'm starting in the world c # (Visual studio 2017), I have an X solution, with several projects, and separating the layers of data access, business logic and so on. Within the frontend project I have libraries, images, webservices, among other things, **one of the web services I must pass it to another solution** !, which is totally different. My question is, how do I pass or know *all* references, classes, components, objects, etc. **that use and/or depending** within the code of the Webservices (they are distributed within the whole solution, that is to say in other projects or codes of other layers). As clear and detailed as possible, for dummies, remember I am starting in this world :-)

Comment: Anyway if you want to re-use a project in another solution, you can do that simply by adding that project to the other solution. Just be careful about dependencies when making changes in one or the other, that you don't break code in the other solution which also relies on the same thing. A more sophisticated alternative might be to package the project code up into packages (e.g Nuget) which you can then include the libraries into as many other projects/solutions as you like, without actually including the source code. Then you can manage the case of multiple versions etc in a better way.

Comment: It's good practice to ensure that business logic is never contained within the project that exposes it (web services, web APIs, WCF, etc.) Put them in their own project, and then create web services, etc. as needed to expose them.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I made a NuGet, however it generates several errors like the following:
 
Error CS0103 The name 'XXXXXXXX' does not exist in the current context eCollectConnectorWeb C: \ ... \ webservice \ yyyyyyy.asmx.cs, but in the references of the project I find what is installed in the NuGet, what can it be?

For dummies please, (sorry for the English)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

167/5000
Solved, I made a NuGet and then solve the errors, conflicts and ambiguities that were presented, but it is a practical solution that saves time and coding.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you want to export a project to another solution, you have to copy physically all files from the source folder to other (from vs 2017, right click on project you want to export, and click on "open folder in resource explorer", to find the exact path). After that in visual studio, in the new solution, right click on solution, add--> existing project --> and select the .proj file of the exported project. Regarding reference you have to check all one by one and add dlls needed.

Comment: "you have to copy fisically _[sic]_ all files from the source folder to other" . That's one way, you don't _have_ to do it like that. You can simply reference the same copy of the project within another solution. Then you don't end up with multiple copies of the same thing, although it does create a dependency between the two solutions, which may not be desirable. Packaging of libraries is probably a better way to achieve the end goal here.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I made a NuGet, however it generates several errors like the following: Error CS0103 The name 'XXXXXXXX' does not exist in the current context eCollectConnectorWeb C: \ ... \ webservice \ yyyyyyy.asmx.cs, but in the references of the project I find what is installed in the NuGet, what can it be? For dummies please, (sorry for the English)

Answer (score 1):

Just to summarise the other answers and comments:

1) In your source folder, physically copy the files required from the old Project to the target Project in the new Solution

2) Launch the new Solution in Visual Studio

3) Select the Project in the Solution Explorer

4) Click the Show All Files button at the top of the Solution Explorer. The files you copied will show with a dotted icon

5) Right click the new files/folders and select Add to Project.